# How to get/put Yahoo contacts in bulk

Tags: python, api, contacts, yahoo, bulk

I'm adding contacts one by one using [Yahoo REST API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts-json_syntax_put) and Python. The set of contacts can be relatively big (around 500), however the API doesn't provide any method that can add bigger parts of my contacts in one request (for example 100 items at once). Maybe someone knows any other way to add multiple contacts at once?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you adding contacts to?

Comment: I'm adding and fetching contacts from Yahoo, it's a kind of import/export mechanism.

Comment: have you tried the count parameter?

Comment: Yes, I did, but this parameter controls completely different thing, namely the maximum number of the returned elements

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the page](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html#contacts-json_syntax_put) linked in your question, the request URL has a count parameter. Have you tried this?

Comment: The `count` parameter is used to indicate the maximum number of parameters that should be returned. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No, I quote from the page I linked to: Number of *contacts* returned.  Did you even try it out?

Comment: I tried this but as you wrote, this parameter refers to the number of the contacts that are **returned**. Maybe I didn't express myself well, but my question is: how to get data of multiple contacts in one request? I'm not interested in limiting the set of the returned items. For example, I send the request with the IDs of the contacts and I expect to obtain the data of **exactly** these contacts that I requested for. Google API supports such operations, the question remains if Yahoo supports it too?